# Integral Calculus.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

What is the anti-derivative of $x\sqrt{(3x^2+7)}$ ? I have tried changing the square root into a fraction as in $x.{(3x^2+7)}^{0.5}$ . I don't know how to go on from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int x\sqrt{3x^2 + 7} \ dx = \frac 16 \int 6x\sqrt{3x^2 + 7} \ dx$$

Letting $u = 3x^2 + 7$

$$\frac 16 \int \sqrt{u} \ du = \frac{1}{9} (3x^2 + 7)^{\frac 32} + C $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the substitution
$ u = 3x^2 + 7$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\displaystyle\int x\sqrt{3x^2+7}dx&=&\displaystyle\int x\sqrt{3x^2+7}dx\cdot\frac{\frac{d(3x^2+7)}{dx}}{\frac{d(3x^2+7)}{dx}}\\
&=&\displaystyle\int x\sqrt{3x^2+7}dx\cdot\frac{\frac{d(3x^2+7)}{dx}}{6x}\\
&=&\displaystyle\frac{1}{6}\int \sqrt{3x^2+7}dx\cdot\frac{d(3x^2+7)}{dx}\\
&=&\displaystyle\frac{1}{6}\int \sqrt{3x^2+7}d(3x^2+7)\\
&=&\displaystyle\frac{1}{6}\int \sqrt{u}du\\
&=&\dots
\end{array}$$